# Google Sheets: how to find the average of values in one column grouped by another column's values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Let's say I have a Google Sheet with the following data:

```
Column1|Column2
A|1
A|2
A|3
A|4
B|1
B|2
```

And I want to find the mean of the values in Column2 grouped by the values of Column1, so output liked the following:

```
A|2.5
B|1.5
```

Should I be looking at [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)? Or using [pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272898?hl=en)?

Comment: If [google-spreadsheet] doesn't have an equivalent of an [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) or [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) then use a [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) divided by a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

Comment: @Jeeped -- I'm not trying to filter by anything, I want to group by values in Column1.

Comment: @maxm Jeeped has actually given you something that would average things for you  e.g. =AVERAGEIF(A2:A7,"=A",B2:B7)   and =AVERAGEIF(A2:A7,"=B",B2:B7) would give you the results you want.  However you would have to give it an explicit value for each set of data ("=A" , "=B" etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a Pivot Table

```
Range: Sheet1!A1:B7

Rows: 
   Group by: Column1

Columns: 
   Group by: Column2

Calculated Field: 
   Forumula: =AVERAGE=(Column2)
   Summarise by: Custom
```

Results

```
            1   2   3   4   Grand Total
A           1   2   3   4   2.5
B           1   2           1.5
Grand Total 1   2   3   4   2.166666667
```

Note: I could not work out how to change the text Grand Total to Average

Answer (score 3):

This formula would also give you the example output:

`=QUERY(A:B,"select A,avg(B) where A <> '' group by A label A '', avg(B) ''")`